# Anaconda is hanging in Solving Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install py2exe using `conda install -c kieranharding py2exe` and pyinstaller but it hangs in solving environment.

I changed `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and `conda config --set channel_priority strict` and `flexible`.

But just keeps hanging. I managed to install in another environment but I want py2exe to install to root env.

Comment: Maybe install py2exe via pip?

Comment: I want to solve also for future installations...

Comment: I don't think it's a bad way to use python libraries manager to install libraries for python :)

Comment: But it installs to different dir so when i export list packages I am not sure the package will be listed

Answer (score 0):

That version is only available for Python 3.4. If you're trying to install this in **base** env, then that command is going to send Conda into trying to figure out how to reconfigure your entire installation to use 3.4, which is a very heavy task.  Instead, create a new env and that shouldn't have the same trouble:

```
conda create -n -c kieranharding python=3.4 py2exe
```

Comment: I also tried to install pyqt5 using ` install -c dsdale24 pyqt5 ` but still hangs??

Comment: any help would be great ??

Answer (score 0):

see my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390283/8691463)

```sh
conda update -n base conda

conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

try it