# creating environment from .yml does not end

Tags: conda

After using the following command in the conda prompt:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

it does not solve the environment.  There is not an error message, only that "Solving environment" never ends.
This worked for me with many other environments.

Here is part of the yaml file:

```
name: x_processing
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - cartopy=0.18.*
  - dask=2.28.*
  - dask-core=2.28.*
  - datashader=0.11.*
  - descartes=1.1.*
  - earthpy=0.9.*
  - esda=2.3.*
  - fiona=1.8.*
  - folium=0.11.*
  - gdal=3.1.*
  - geographiclib=1.*
  - geojson=2.5.*
  - geopandas=0.8.*
  - geoplot=0.4.*
  - geopy=2.0.*
  - geos=3.8.*
  - geoviews=1.8.*
  - hdf4=4.2.*
  - hdf5=1.10.*
  - holoviews=1.13.*
  - ipykernel=5.3.*
  - ipython=7.18.*
  - ipywidgets=7.5.*
  - jupyter=1.0.*
  - jupyterlab=2.2.*
  - mapclassify=2.3.*
  - matplotlib=3.3.*
  - netcdf4=1.5.*
  - networkx=2.*
  - notebook=6.1.*
  - numpy=1.19.*
  - osmnx=0.16.*
  - owslib=0.20.*
  - pandas=1.1.*
  - pillow=7.2.*
  - proj=7.1.*
  - pyproj=2.6.1.post1
  - pysal=2.3.*
  - pytables=3.6.*
  - python=3.7.*
  - rasterio=1.1.*
  - rasterstats=0.14.*
  - requests=2.24.*
  - scikit-image=0.17.*
  - scikit-learn=0.23.*
  - scipy=1.5.*
  - seaborn=0.11.*
  - shapely=1.7.*
  - urllib3=1.24.*
```

Conda version : conda 4.11.0

I tried some solutions:
[Updating base conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208900/anaconda-is-hanging-in-solving-environment)
[Modifying the channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734508/stuck-at-solving-environment-on-anaconda)

Comment: The environment is apparently quite complex to solve. What OS are you on? Please include the complete yml file. You could also try to use `mamba` here: `conda install mamba` and then `mamba create -f environment.yml`

Comment: Thank you, I will try with mamba. I am using Windows 10, and I have added all the libraries in that environment. Do you suggest to use only the minimum dependencies and then install one by one when needed?

Comment: This environment is highly pinned - is that intentional? i.e. this file communicates that `matplotlib` **must** be version 3.3.x, that 3.5+ and 3.3- are not acceptable. Some of these versions are relatively old, as well.

Comment: Thank you. I had this definition of dependencies from an external source. You are right, they are out of date. I will create a simpler environment, then.

Comment: Solving of this env succedes on linux, but not windows. I think some of these packages are simply not available for windows and python 3.7 in the specified version

Comment: I deleted all of the dependencies except two, and it worked. I guess that I "overloaded" the environment. Thank you very much